# django queryset union not working with only

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, django-queryset

I have 2 `querysets` and I am applying `union` on them but the strange thing is when I use `only`, it is selecting all fields from DB, and when I use `values`, it is selecting only given fields.

This is selecting all fields from the `Physician` table

```
doctors_models.Physician.objects.filter(
    appointments__member=self.context['member']
).union(doctors_models.Physician.objects.filter(
    appointments__booked_by=self.context['member']
)).only('id', 'name_prefix', 'first_name', 'middle_name', 'last_name', 'name_suffix')
```

BUT
This is selecting only specified fields from the `Physician` table

```
doctors_models.Physician.objects.filter(
    appointments__member=self.context['member']
).union(doctors_models.Physician.objects.filter(
    appointments__booked_by=self.context['member']
)).values('id', 'name_prefix', 'first_name', 'middle_name', 'last_name', 'name_suffix')
```

However, this is also selecting only specified fields but why should I define fields 2 times.

```
doctors_models.Physician.objects.filter(
    appointments__member=self.context['member']
).only('id', 'name_prefix', 'first_name', 'middle_name', 'last_name', 'name_suffix').union(
    doctors_models.Physician.objects.filter(
        appointments__booked_by=self.context['member']
).only('id', 'name_prefix', 'first_name', 'middle_name', 'last_name', 'name_suffix'))
```

Comment: if you have union both parts have to have same number of fields

Comment: It has the same fields.

Comment: No it does not as only limits fields that are used in SELECT query, also you could do it properly in single query by utilizing Q objects, Willem already explained it in details

Answer (score 2):

> However, this is also selecting only specified fields but why should I define fields 2 times?

Because the number of columns and their types of both `SELECT` statements should match, as is specified in the [documentation on **`.union(…)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#union):

> Passing different models works as long as the **`SELECT` list is the same in all `QuerySet`s** (at least **the types**, the names don’t matter as long as the types are in the same order). In such cases, you must use the column names from the first `QuerySet` in `QuerySet` methods applied to the resulting `QuerySet`.

That being said, please don't use `.union(…)` in the first place for this. You can merge the two conditions by wrapping these in `Q` objects and combining these with an "*or*":

```
from django.db.models import Q

doctors_models.Physician.objects.filter(
    Q(appointments__member=self.context['member']) |
    Q(appointments__booked_by=self.context['member'])
).only('id', 'name_prefix', 'first_name', 'middle_name', 'last_name', 'name_suffix')
```

Furthermore using [**`.only(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#only) or [**`.defer(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#defer) is only advisable for columns that contain a large amount of data. For "small" columns, it will often not have a significant impact, and in case you later need these fields, it can even result in *N+1 problems*.

Comment: 1. OR query will result in "index will not be used" that's why using union.
2. using `only` so that it does not fetch all fields unnecessary.
3. You said union works when columns in both query are same and they are in my query. Are you seeing different columns?

Comment: @SHIVAMJINDAL: if you undex both columns separately, normally it will use the two indexes. Often *internally* a database rewrites it to a UNION, but the advantage is that you thus do not write two `SELECT` statements yourself: http://www.orafaq.com/tuningguide/logical%20operators.html

Comment: @Willen Is this written somewhere that  mysql automatically convert OR query into union

Comment: @SHIVAMJINDAL: A good database collects statistics and makes a query plan based on the statistics. If you make a query and the database expects to return a huge chunk of the rows, it will not use an index, scanning the table is then more efficient (since even if it uses the index, later it will have to scan to return records). The queryplan is based on the [*selectivity* of the indexes](https://www.akadia.com/services/ora_index_selectivity.html). This thus means that if the number of distinct `booked_by`s in the `appointments` relation is low, it will not use an index.

Comment: @SHIVAMJINDAL: the query plan is thus not just determined by the query, but also about the number of records the database expects to retrieve. If the selectivity is 0.7, it expects to retrieve an large amount of records.

Comment: @SHIVAMJINDAL: if your database has already representative data (as in records that are similar to the real situation), you can use [**`.explain()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#explain) to determine how MYSQL will run the query.